# Gradle task not being found after copy to sub folders

Tags: gradle

I am relatively new to gradle.  Using a gradle task, I copied 'build.gradle', 'gradle.properties' files to one of the subfolders.

Now, I want to run a task from the copied build.gradle from the same task that copied the files.  When I try to do this, I get 'Task not found' error.

The path that I am referring to seems to be proper.  Can someone explain me what is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: So you have a Gradle task that copies build files around and that taks should after copying call a task from the new subproject? That is not possible because the project has already been configured once the copy tasks starts to run. By that time you cannot change the project structure by putting build files somewhere.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle files? Without some code, it's hard to figure this out